# Is it possible to have an app titled "X" with a title "Y" below its icon in the launcher?

Tags: android, icons, label

I have an Android app with a pretty long name. This name is 'compacted' when presented under the app icon in the launcher (tested on 2.2 up to 4.0). That's both ugly and stupid (you can't see the actual app name).

I would like to change this icon label without affecting the name that can be seen in the App Manager. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. The caption of your launcher icon is driven by the [`android:label`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label) attribute of whatever `<activity>` has the magic `<intent-filter>` to appear in the `LAUNCHER`. By default, that is set up to be the same string resource (`@string/app_name`) as is used for the `<application>` `android:label`, but you can have your `<activity>` point to a different string resource.

Comment: Doesn't the label affect the app title in the app manager? I.e. when you choose to uninstall it or just view running apps...

Comment: @NOPslider: The `android:label` on `<application>` controls what you look like in Manage Applications. The `android:label` on `<activity>` controls what the caption is for that specific activity, just as `android:icon` on `<activity>` controls the icon for that activity. `<activity>` can inherit those values from `<application>`, but you override them in `<activity>` as needed.

Comment: Hm. That's the problem. I can't specify a different short name for the icon label and 'Manage Applications' label. Correct?

Comment: @NOPslider: I do not know how many different ways I can write this. Let's try boldface. **`android:label` on `<application>` controls Manage Applications. `android:label` on `<activity>` controls the launcher icon caption**.